# I need a make zip for the multiple files using JSZip on nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, download, nuxt.js, jszip

I Want to make zip for the multiple file using JSZip on nuxtjs and i want the files are convert to base64 format to pdf and also file format is any.If all files are in jpg then it convert to jpeg and if all files are in pdf then it convert list of pdf and put in the zip folder.

I want to do this vuejs or nuxtjs with JSZip package.

I use this below code but not getting anything.

```
    download_btn() {
var zip = new JSZip()
var img = zip.folder("images")
for (i = 0; i < this.image.length; i++) {
img.file("img.png", this.image[i].imageurl)
}
zip.generateAsync({
type: "blob"
}).then(function(content) {
saveAs(content, "img_archive.zip")
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about JSZip, but for Nuxtjs you can create a plugin to call it.

Should be something in the likes of:

1. Install JSZip via npm:

```js
npm install jszip
```

2. Create a file plugins/jszip.js. Inside plugins/jszip.js add:

```js
/* ~/plugins/jszip.js */

import Vue from 'vue'
import JSZip from 'jszip'

Vue.use(JSZip)
```

3. Add the reference to the plugin on nuxt.config.js. I'm guessing that it should run on the visitor's browser, so you should include 'mode: client'. This will make it bypass the Server-Side-Rendering.

```js
export default {
 ...
  plugins: [
      { src: '~/plugins/jszip', mode: 'client' }
    ]
 ...
  }
```

4. You may try your code like this:

```js
download_btn() {
  var img = JSZip.folder("images")
  for (i = 0; i < this.image.length; i++) {
    img.file("img.png", this.image[i].imageurl)
  }
  JSZip.generateAsync({
    type: "blob"
  }).then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "img_archive.zip")
  })
}
```

You can read more here: [NuxtJS / Plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Download [jszip](http://github.com/Stuk/jszip/zipball/master) manually and it to your static folder in nuxt.
In nuxt-config under script section add `{ src: '/js/jszip.js' },`.